# Is it possible to carry RS232 signals over a USB cable?

Tags: usb, rs232

Is it possible to carry RS232 signals (115200 baud rate) over a USB cable? I don't want to use FTDI's RS232-USB converters. I just want to carry TXD, RXD and GND signals over a USB cable. Are my signals affected from external noise badly?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly u r going to do! Anyway, you cannot carry serial signals through USB protocol unless u use a convertor which provides a virtual COM port. But if u just want to use a USB cable for transferring serial signals that has nothing to do with USB protocol, yes u can.

Comment: Actually, I won't use USB protocol. DB9 connector is too big for my design, therefore I will just use USB connector and USB cable.

Comment: So it seems it's ok to use USB cables, regarding the fact that usb speed is much more than uart speed, so a USB cable seems to be able to handle the uart transferring.

Comment: It is fairly common to use RJ45 connectors for serial. There is no standard, some known pinouts are shown on [Zonker's Serial Signals Page](https://www.conserver.com/consoles/Signals/signals.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about "external noise". The USB wires are differentially coupled TWISTED PAIRs, so you will be badly affected by signal coupling if the cable is long.

Comment: Yes but USB cables are normally short.  I would expect it to work but I would just test it with lower drive voltage, longer cable

Comment: @KalleMP, yes, they are short (no more than 5 meters), and if you lower the signaling frequency and limit signal edge rise time, it will work. And the good point (by Elliot Alderson) is that there will be a confusion with USB-look-alike  cables/ports

Answer (score 9):

You can carry RS232 over a barbed-wire fence if you want to, at least for a short distance. But it would be a bad idea, just like using USB cables would be a bad idea. The danger of improper connection and equipment damage is too great. You should use a different connector and cable system.

Comment: I agree on the danger of connection error, but electrically OP should be fine. USB by itself is short distance.

Comment: I'd be impressed by a TDR that can tell me the distance between barbs.

Comment: I agree. While certainly possible, it is extremely bad idea to use an existing connector that is for specific purpose to something else that may damage when connected. If you need a small connector, ready-made RS232 cables with something like 3.5mm TRS connectors exist. Unless you want to integrate USB-RS232 adapter module (not cable) inside your device.

Comment: Aww, I wanted to mention the barb wire, you beat me to it.